# Error in FIND_IN_SET

Tags: php, mysql, select

i am getting result in phpadmin for this query but getting error in php(`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`)

```
select * from luxury_properties LP,property_type PT,cities C 
where (FIND_IN_SET('2',LP.luxury_property_feature_id) OR 
       FIND_IN_SET('7',LP.luxury_property_feature_id) ) 
AND LP.property_type_id = PT.property_type_id 
AND LP.city=C.city_id 
AND LP.status=1 
order by LP.property_price DESC
```

Where `LP.luxury_property_feature_id` is comma separated value

What is the issue in this query?

### Updated:

I am executing like this

```
$str='';
if(is_array($luxPropFeatures) && $luxPropFeatures != 0)
{
    $selCount = count($luxPropFeatures);
    if($selCount >1){
        foreach($luxPropFeatures as $val){
            $str .= " OR FIND_IN_SET('".$val."',LP.luxury_property_feature_id) ";
            $str[0]='';$str[1]='';
        }
    }else{
        foreach($luxPropFeatures as $val) {
            $str = " FIND_IN_SET('".$val."',LP.luxury_property_feature_id) ";
        }
    }
}


$sql = "select * from luxury_properties LP,property_type PT,cities C 
        WHERE (".$str.") 
        AND LP.property_type_id = PT.property_type_id 
        AND LP.city=C.city_id 
        AND LP.status=1 
        order by LP.property_price DESC";
```

Where `$luxPropFeatures` is checkbox selected array

Comment: Show the code how you execute this query.

Comment: There's no syntax error in this query.

Comment: You are getting an erro in the first line at the first character. That means you are executing it wrong. Is it part of a script?

Comment: My guess it the PHP variable $some_value that you use to get '2' or '7' is not set. Try var_dump()-ing it to the screen, and see for yourself. The query you posted looks fine.

Comment: Hi,updated my question please check it

Comment: You are missing the interesting part where you **execute** the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i fixed the issue,

```
if($selCount >1){
    foreach($luxPropFeatures as $val) {
    $str .="OR FIND_IN_SET('".$val."',LP.luxury_property_feature_id) ";
    $trimmed = ltrim($str, "OR"); 
     //$str[0]='';$str[2]='';
     }
}else{

    foreach($luxPropFeatures as $val) {
        $trimmed = "FIND_IN_SET('".$val."',LP.luxury_property_feature_id) ";
    }

}
```

Previously i tried to escape the `OR` [`OR FIND_IN_SET('2',LP.luxury_property_feature_id) OR FIND_IN_SET('7',LP.luxury_property_feature_id)`]character for the first time like `$str[0]='';$str[2]='';`

Instead of set null, i trimmed the first two char using ltrim [`$trimmed = ltrim($str, "OR");` ]

Now its working fine, thanks for the support.